# redirect old url with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a website, example: example.com

I want to redirect with .htaccess a url to b url:

a: /global/index.php?option=about
b: /news/group/13/

I test & search many times but no result!

this is my code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RedirectMatch ^(.*)about(.*)$  http://example.com/news/group/13/$1

RedirectMatch ^/global/index.php?option=about$  http://example.com/news/group/13/$1

RedirectMatch ^/index.php?option=about$  http://example.com/news/group/13/$1

Redirect permanent /global/index.php?option=about example.com/news/group/13/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**option=about** is part of querystring in your url and you can not test it using RedirectMatch pa and Redirect directive. You need to capture it using %{QUERY_STRING} variable

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=about$
RewriteRule ^ /news/group/13? [L,R]
```

An empty question mark **?** at the end of the destination path is important as it discards the old querystring from new url.